# Split PDF separate some pages without losing quality in Linux terminal

Tags: bash, pdf

I have a big PDF and I only need the pages 2-6, 12-33 and 80.

How can I separate them and put the files together on a Linux shell without losing quality?

When I use

```
convert *.pdf[1-5,11,32,79] output.pdf
```

I have the pages in one new PDF but with bad quality.

Answer (score 1):

Found an solution:

> pdftk is a useful multi-platform tool for the job (pdftk homepage).
>
> ```
> pdftk full-pdf.pdf cat 12-15 output outfile_p12-15.pdf
> ```
>
> you pass the filename of the main pdf, then you tell it to only
>   include certain pages (12-15 in this example) and output it to a new
>   file.

from https://askubuntu.com/questions/221962/how-can-i-extract-a-page-range-a-part-of-a-pdf

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `pdfjoin` (which is part of `TeXLive`).

```
pdfjoin -o output.pdf mybig.pdf '1-5,11,32,79'
```

Answer (score 0):

With excellent [QPDF](https://github.com/qpdf/qpdf) is very simple (mind the double dash `--`, is not an error).

```
qpdf in.pdf out.pdf --pages in.pdf 2-6,12-33,80 -- --split-pages
```

to split all pages as single file even simpler

```
qpdf in.pdf out.pdf --split-pages
```

Source
https://github.com/qpdf/qpdf/issues/30#issuecomment-322019098